# Hiding Ribbon using SPTrim for Sharepoint 2010 shows background color of div with id s4-ribbonrow

Tags: sharepoint

I am trying to hide ribbon for some users using code below:
Code:

This is working fine, but div with id s4-ribbonrow has some some background color which is still visible. How to make it invisible for same set of users?

Answer (score 0):

You can use SharePoint Security Trim.
Example:
 
SharePoint:SPSecurityTrimmedControl runat="server" Permissions="Your Custom Permission Level">
script>
Your custom code>
/script>
/SharePoint:SPSecurityTrimmedControl>
 in your master page for that particular control.